# infinispan cartridge with Hotrod in OpenShift

Tags: caching, openshift, infinispan, socket-timeout-exception

I have created a scaled application and added Infinispan Cartridge from the below URL:

raw.github.com/bdecoste/openshift-origin-cartridge-infinispan/master/metadata/manifest.yml

Now I want to connect to the infinispan server from the application running in seperate gear. I am using hotrod-client. properties having the following content:

infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list = $OPENSHIFT_INIFINISPAN_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_INFINISPAN_TCP_PROXY_PORT; infinispan.client.hotrod.socket_timeout = 500 infinispan.client.hotrod.connect_timeout = 10

When I run the application I get the following in the error logs:

ISPN004007: Exception encountered. Retry 9 out of 10: org.infinispan.client.hotrod. exceptions.TransportException:: java.net.SocketTimeoutException at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readByte(TcpTransport.java:184) [i nfinispan-client-hotrod-5.2.1.Final.jar:5.2.1.Final]

what causes this and how we can resolve?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not communicate between gears that are not part of the scaled application unless it is over port 80,443,8000,8443 using your public url.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have used $OPENSHIFT_INIFINISPAN_HOST = 530c74b75973---52000357-abc.rhcloud.com and $OPENSHIFT_INFINISPAN_TCP_PROXY_PORT = 53043 , it should connect with the seperate gear but its not. Is it a bug? because the same thing works with mysql hosted in scaled application's gear.

Comment: Hi , I didn't get any response. Please reply waiting for the respone. Thanks a lot again

Comment: I think that will only work within a scaled application, otherwise gears can not talk to each other.

Comment: Hi I have created a scaled app only :(